# How to remove Kubectl from ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes

I've followed [guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/) to install kubectl for testing in development environment on Ubuntu 16.04.

Now I would like to remove Kubectl from ubuntu.

Comment: snap remove kubectl

Comment: snap list kubectl

Answer (score 44):

Depending on the method you chose in https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/, it can be any of these:

- Install kubectl binary via curl: `sudo rm /usr/local/bin/kubectl`
- Download as part of the Google Cloud SDK: `gcloud components remove kubectl`
- Install with snap on Ubuntu (just as Gparmar said): `snap remove kubectl`

In addition, you may need to remove the configuration files in `~/.kube`.

Comment: Is there no configuration files or something related to kubectl elsewhere, which should be deleted? What about ~/.kube ?

Comment: In your answer, it should be `~/.kube` instead of `~./kube`.

Comment: Damn! I wrote it too fast :) Thanks again

Comment: to remove config use below command.
`sudo rm -rf ~/.kube`

Answer (score -3):

```sh
sudo -i
```

Once you get root access then apply command

```sh
unset DOCKER_HOST
```

You can use `unset DOCKER_HOST` command to remove/unset the Kubernetes service.

Comment: Docker, Kubernetes ?!? How does it match? What if my server is also a Docker server that I don't want to uninstall?